# Is underclocked Xeon e3-1230v3 the same as e3-1230Lv3?

Tags: processor, power

I am looking for a low wattage CPU with relative high performance. I read on several places, that underclocking or undervolting cheaper normal processors (e.g. Xeon e3-1230v3) can have the same result as buying a rare and more expensive L or T version (e.g. Xeon e3-1230Lv3) of the same processor. Is this true, or should I buy the more expensive low wattage version?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is that it depends. If the one processor is faster than another, you can definitely undervolt the processor, or underclock it to slow it down. It would be dependent on how much you undervolt or underclock the processor, however. You might also want to note that you would want to make sure that your motherboard can support overclocking so you can ensure that you can actually mess around with the processor states and voltages.

Also note that the [power consumption scales linearly with frequency and quadratically with voltage](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/34766/how-does-power-consumption-vary-with-the-processor-frequency-in-a-typical-comput). So you can also reduce the frequency on a cpu state to lower power consumption as well, but it is more effective to decrease voltage because it has a squared relationship with power consumption.

Comment: The normal version is 3.3GHz with 3.7GHz turbo, the low wattage version is 1.8GHz with 2.8GHz turbo. Is it possible to set the turbo frequency, not just the base frequency? I am not that familiar with oc. Memory voltages are the same, but I guess that does not mean anything.

Comment: You can essentially think about Intel turbo technology as a 'tentative overclock'. If all you want to do is slow down the turbo frequency, you can just install [Intel's Extreme Overclocking Utility](https://downloadcenter.intel.com/download/24075/Intel-Extreme-Tuning-Utility-Intel-XTU-) which is a very easy to use overclocking interface, no calculations required. Unless your core in unlocked, however; your ability to fine tune the processor states will be limited.